# Передача переменных в си

Tags: c

ProkletyiPira прав...
Картина такая. 
Я полный нуб в программировании(только в начале пути и многие элементарные задачи для меня являются проблемой)
Взбрело мне в голову создать программу которая получает текущей путь по средствам приведенного ниже алгоритма

```
char* dir;  
int len =50;  
getcwd(dir, len);  
printf("Current directory is %s\n", dir);
```

допустим я запустил скомпилированный код из директории /home/user
переменная dir принимает вид /home/user
дальше я хочу прочитать файлы и папки из данной директории следующем алгоритмом

```
DIR *dir;
struct dirent *ent;
char directory[255] = "./";<< вот сюда я хочу передать текущею директорию  
dir = opendir(directory);
while ((ent=readdir(dir)) != NULL){
    printf("%s\n", ent->d_name);
}
closedir(dir);
```

но поскольку `char directory[255] = "./";` принимает параметр в кавычках, а я передаю переменную из первого алгоритма без кавычек, то компилятор меня кроет благим матом...  примеры из книги... это не готовый код... хочу понять принцип взаимодействия

Comment: прям так и передайте: 

    char directory[255] = "/home/user";

Comment: я бы с радостью...
но как добавить >>"<< к  >>/home/user<<  без кавычек?
переменную я получаю >>/home/user<< именно в таком виде ! без кавычек !..

Comment: бррррр...что значит "без кавычек"? Кавычки должны обрамлять строковый литерал согласно ситнаксису языка. Если вы напишете 
  
    char directory[255] = "/home/user"

то никаких кавычек в вашей переменной **directory** разумеется не будет. Там будет только **/home/user**

Comment: что то не вижу получения **`/home/user`**... как именно вы получаете?

покажите код и ошибки...

если я правильно понял то **`/home/user`** получается на этапе выполнения... тогда почитайте как работать со строками в С\С++\STL тогда сразу всё станет ясно. (если нужен только "С" то С++\STL читать ненадо)

Comment: так какие именно ошибки вам указывает компилятор?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

И после обновления поста всё равно непонятно что конкретно не работает, и зачем нужно куда-то приделать кавычки.

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char dirname[NAME_MAX];
    DIR *dirh;
    struct dirent *dirent;

    getcwd(dirname, sizeof(dirname)-1);
    printf("Current directory is %s\n", dirname);

    dirh = opendir(dirname);
    while( dirent=readdir(dirh) )
    {
        printf("%s\n", dirent->d_name);
    }
    closedir(dirh);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: вот оно че!!! Спасибо!!! теперь дошло!!!)))